# Timeout a submit animation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, button, timeout, submit

i have a submit button and a JavaScript. On click the button changes the state from active to inactive and a spinner animation is shown. I want to add to the script a **timeout function**. The button shall stop the animation and go back in active state after 3000 ms and show the normal submit button again. Here is my code:

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="submit" id="ajax-form-button">Submit</button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#ajax-form").submit(function(e) {
   // disable button
   $('#ajax-form-button').prop("disabled", true);
   // add spinner to button
   $('#ajax-form-button').html(
   `<i class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mb-1"></i> Bitte warten...`
   );            
 });
});
```

Comment: Something like an *abort submit*??? What have you tried? I don't see any `setTimeout`, `e.preventDefault()` or ajax request here...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette i dont want to handle it with my ajax request. I want just a stupid timer for 3 seconds. After 3 seconds the button shall shown again in original state as shown in the HTML code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`window.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) is what you are looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ajax-form").submit(function(e) {
    // disable button
    $('#ajax-form-button').prop("disabled", true);
    // add spinner to button
    $('#ajax-form-button').html(
      `<i class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mb-1"></i> Bitte warten...`
    );

    window.setTimeout(() => {
      $('#ajax-form-button').prop("disabled", false); //re-enable button
      $('#ajax-form-button').html("Submit"); // oder "Absenden"  
    }, 3000) // run that function after 3 s

  });
});
```

Comment: Great, works exactly the way i want! Thank you so much!